# how to redirect the search result from google web search api

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm having home and search page in my asp.net website.
In home page ,I'm going to use search box powered by Google by using Google web search API (not custom search).
When i click search button(executing the search) in home page,i want to display the search result in search page.
can anyone tell me how to redirect the search result to another page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need: [link](http://www.google.com/adsense/support/as/bin/answer.py?answer=160528)

Comment: right, or if you want open the result in a frame on your site and show a parent frame with your main content. But really it comes down to what you mean by redirecting.

Comment: By redirecting, I mean sending the results to an another page. As per given requirement i need to send the search results to a different page

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not sure why you would want to do this. But if I understand the question correctly, you could open the search result in a 1x1 pixel frame and load any page you want in the parent frame.